Elasticsearch - How to Search for Exact Matches of One Word or Multi-Word Strings in Documents
I'm having issues getting the elasticsearch results i need in a Laravel app.
My mappings look like this:
'index' => 'adverts',  // Name of the index to create
'body' => [
    'mappings' => [
        'properties' => [
            'id' => ['type' => 'integer'],
            'title' => ['type' => 'text'],
            'content' => ['type' => 'text'],
        ]
    ],
]

Currently the PHP code for the query looks like this (this does not return correct records):
public function searchAdverts(string $query)
{
    $params = [
        'index' => 'adverts',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query'  => "{$query}",
                    'fields' => ['title', 'content'],
                    'type'   => 'phrase_prefix'

                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $response = $this->client->search($params);
    return $response;
}

How do I modify my PHP Elasticsearch query or mappings to find exact matches of a string within documents?
This SQL returns the desired result:
SELECT id, title, content FROM adverts WHERE title LIKE '%$query%' OR content LIKE '%$query%';


Since you’re using Laravel, you’re in luck! I’ve authored a package that lets you leverage Laravel’s Eloquent to run Elasticsearch queries without dealing with complex DSL objects. Have a look here https://github.com/pdphilip/laravel-elasticsearch
In your case, you would create an Advert model to map to your adverts index, then simply:
$results = Advert::where('title', $query)->orWhere('content', $query)->get();

Docs: https://elasticsearch.pdphilip.com/querying-models#where
Side note: Since Elasticsearch will match tokens, you can use a normal where clause to search for partial matches which it seems you need here;

If you wanted the exact value you would use whereExact('title',$query)
If you wanted to search within tokens you would use where('color','like','bl) for black or blue

Edit:
If you go:
$dsl = Advert::where('title', $query)->orWhere('content', $query)->toDsl();

You get:
$dsl = [
    'index' => 'adverts',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                [
                                    'match' => [
                                        'title' => $query,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                [
                                    'match' => [
                                        'content' => $query,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        '_source' => [
            '*',
        ],
    ],
];

Grab this DSL if you prefer.
